# How to stop books closing themselves

Tags: books

I have a book on programming, which means that I need to look at it when I am on my computer (meaning that I don't have any hands available for keeping the book open). The only problem is, it keeps closing itself.

What is there I could do to keep it open? It would be best if the solution is already an item the house instead of buying something.

Since this is on an uneven surface, a weight won't work since it would just fall off.

Comment: similar: http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/10853/book-holder-for-paperbacks/

Comment: Clothespins or spring-type paper clips?

Comment: @jamesqf I tried paper clips before I posted this, however, they are too lite

Comment: @iProgram: I don't mean regular paper clips (the sort that are made from bent wire), but the spring-type ones like this: http://www.staples.com/Staples-Black-Metal-Binder-Clips/product_SS271759  Or the similar gadgets that are used to e.g. close a bag of chips.

Comment: @jamesqf So binder clips then? :)

Comment: called a "bulldog clip" in the UK, although a good laundry clothes peg would do just as well.

Answer (score 16):

You can just use your pen cap to clamp a bunch of pages so that it would not fly.
Its easy and you don't need to buy anything.

[image: you can see in that image]

Comment: Heaviside unit step function....hmm.

Answer (score 12):

Make book holder out of old metal hangers.

[image: metal hanger instructions]

Refer [artistshelpingchildren.org](http://www.artistshelpingchildren.org/kidscraftsactivitiesblog/2012/03/how-to-make-a-wire-hanger-book-holder/) for detailed steps to achieve it.

Or [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qAQKDKvJOOk).

Or just buy a book clip:

[image: example of metal hanger keeping book open]

Book clips are quite cheaper than the book holders.

Answer (score 9):

I simply use a string. For example when playing piano and wanting to keep the book open on a certain page, I slip the book between the lid and a string that I always have around the lid. 
[image]

Answer (score 8):

Binder clips fits perfectly for this application.

They are also used for various other purposes.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I am using hair clip when I need to hold the songbook while playing the piano.
The advantage of this is mainly that it is large enough to hold the whole book and not only a few pages.

[image: hair clip]

[image: hair clip holding a book]

Answer (score 4):

Just take a large rubber band that will fit over the book from side to side and once you have the page you want....slip the elastic over the book near the top. You can increase the number of elastics for larger books or slip a chop stick under the elastic for more rigidity and stiffness.

Answer (score 1):

Surprised nobody has mentioned book stands. I am looking to buy "WIZ book stand" as used by youtuber "The Man Sitting Next to Me" in his study live streams. Seems to be a solid solution given you have the physical space. Links below.

The Man Sitting Next to Me's: https://amzn.to/2M9aVVW

Another one, highly rated: [https://www.amazon.com/BestBookStand-Nice-Production-Bookstand-Bookstands/dp/B00MVBDLFC/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MVBDLFC)

Comment: "`It would be best if the solution is already an item in the house instead of buying something`" This is why no one has mentioned it. Thanks for letting me know anyway.

Comment: Oh sorry, missed that! Well the only option here that both holds books open **and** upright is the wire hanger, but it sucks to be blunt.. It's just too light weight, so this is looking like my only choice

Comment: laundry peg....

Answer (score 0):

Get Something that is flat and has more weight than the book.Then place it behind the book.Then get a binder clip and put it on the weighted side of the book.Then lay the book down on something and then you will never lose the page.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 (If possible)
Bend the book backwards. (Opposite of closing it).
Step 2.
Check if it worked. If Flip to a different page and repeat step 1.
Step 3.
Enjoy!

I looked this thread up and nothing was useful. This made the stubborn Kip S. Thorne time travel book (closes extremely) just 'die'. Now my time travel book is happy.

Step 4 (if needed).
Stomp on the book. (Not joking, this is a very delicate stomping. The human weight would probably win the fight.).

Buying Kip Throne's book was very difficult because of this battle.
I won in a few seconds.
No buying.
No searching.
100% free.

Now I can finally read it after these months. Luckily that book I have responds well to these methods. I didn't have to stomp this time. Some notebooks don't play nice. Stomping on the middle-thing fixes that. Now I can read it no matter how sleepy I am.

Should've done this a month ago.